# Preseting mandatory string options in syntax with default value

Tags: stata, stata-macros

Consider the following toy program:

```
program define table_v1.01, rclass
version 15
syntax varlist(fv min = 1 max = 1) [if] [in], pat_ID(string) = Patient_ID
end
```

I would like to make the option `pat_ID` compulsory.

In addition, since 90% of the time its value will be `Patient_ID`, how can I set this as a default value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
program define foo, rclass

syntax varlist(fv min = 1 max = 1) [if] [in], [pat_ID(string)]

if "`pat_ID'" == "" local pat_ID Patient_ID
display "`pat_ID'"

end
```

Example:

```
. foo i.foreign
Patient_ID

. foo i.foreign, pat_ID(Other_ID)
Other_ID
```

Unlike other types of options (for example those accepting integers or reals), you cannot directly set a default value for strings. Typing `help syntax` will provide you with information about what is possible.